# replacing words on multiple strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random

I'm trying to figure out how to replace instances of a number/letter arrangement, with a random number, in many strings, within an array, while also randomly generating one of those strings on each click.

Essentially, I want to randomly generate one of my strings from my array on click, and replace the '6a' with a random number.

I've been able to generate a random string per click, and I was able to replace the number in a string if I removed all other strings in my array, but I can't get everything to work together. This is what my code looks like so far!

Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
//strings that I want to generate and change

var events = ['String one 6a',
  
'String two 6a',

'String three 6a',

'String four 6a',

'String five 6a',

];

//function click generating new random string

function newEvent() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (events.length));
  var b = randomNumber;
  document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = events[b];
};

//attempt to change part of a string to a random number

function numChange() {
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      events[i] = events[i].replace('6a', function(match) {
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
      } );
  };
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="thing">
    <p>
      We're replacing this thing
    </p>
  </div>
  <button onclick="newEvent()">
    Click me
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to have happen. If you want to run `numChange` on the click of the button, call it in `newEvent`: `function newEvent() { numChange(); ... }`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to happen as well. Please edit your question and clearly explain the initial state, what the user will do and what the results should be.

Comment: Sorry! I'll try to edit this and make it more clear. The `numChange` function was just me trying to replace `6a` before the `newEvent` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over array with strings do this.

```js
var events = [
  'String one ',
  'String two ',
  'String three ',
  'String four ',
  'String five '
];

function newEvent() {
  var randomArrayString = Math.floor(Math.random() * (events.length));
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = events[randomArrayString] + randomNumber;
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="thing">
    <p>
      We're replacing this thing
    </p>
  </div>
  <button onclick="newEvent()">
    Click me
  </button>
</body>
```

If you don't have control over array strings use regexp in `str.replace()`

```js
var events = [
'String one 6a',
  'String two 6a',
  'String three 6a',
  'String four 6a',
  'String five 6a'
];

function newEvent() {
  var randomArrayId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (events.length));
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = events[randomArrayId].replace(/6a/,randomNumber);
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="thing">
    <p>
      We're replacing this thing
    </p>
  </div>
  <button onclick="newEvent()">
    Click me
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I was probably overthinking things and this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Keep it simple, it helping ;-]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one clean and simple solution:

```js
let events = ['String one 6a',
  
'String two 6a',

'String three 6a',

'String four 6a',

'String five 6a',

];

function numChange() { 
  events = events.map(event => event.replace('6a', Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)));
};

function newEvent() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (events.length));
  document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = events[randomNumber]
};

//execute once to replace '6a' with a random number
numChange();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="thing">
    <p>
      We're replacing this thing
    </p>
  </div>
  <button onclick="newEvent()">
    Click me
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks super clean and really close to what I was trying to create on my own. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome @darmeg. If you consider this as an useful answer, I would appreciate if you rate it as 'useful'

Answer (score -1):

Should be like:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, htm, M, I, S, Q, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
var events = ['String one 6a', 'String two 6a', 'String three 6a', 'String four 6a', 'String five 6a'];
I('f').onsubmit = function(){
  return false;
}
function randEventRep(){
  return events[Math.floor(Math.random()*events.length)].replace(/\b6a\b/g, Math.floor(Math.random()*7));
}
var press = I('press'), thing = I('thing');
press.onclick = function(){
  thing.innerHTML = randEventRep();
}
} // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='f' name='f'>
      <p id='thing'>This is the thing we&apos;re changing</p>
      <input id='press' type='button' value='Click Me' />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I think it's too complicated for me since I'm a beginner. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: What's so complicated about it? There are extra functions for getting Elements there, but this is very, very, very simple. It's also a better way to code since it keeps JavaScript separate from HTML.